# Give an upper bound for $E\left[\exp\left({\frac{nt}{\sum_{i=1}^n k_i}}\right)\right]$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, expectation

Given an upper bound for $E \left[ \exp \left(\frac{nt}{\sum_{i=1}^n k_i}\right)\right]$ where

- $k_i$'s are random variables which denote the number of independent
  Bernoulli trials before we encounter the first failure where
  probability of failure is $p$
- $n$ is the number of such Bernoulli trial experiments performed
- $E[X]$ denotes the expected value of a random variable $X$
- $e$ = $exp$ is the base of the natural logarithm
- $t > 0$ is some arbitrary parameter

What I have done so far:

My original task was to derive an upper bound for

$$Pr \left( \frac{n}{ \sum_{i=1}^n k_i} - p \ge \delta \right)$$

$$ = Pr \left( e^{t \frac{n}{\sum_{i=1}^n k_i} - p } \ge e^{t\delta} \right)$$

Here $t > 0$. I applied Markov's Inequality to get

$$Pr \left( e^{t \frac{n}{\sum_{i=1}^n k_i} - p } \ge e^{t\delta} \right)$$

$$ \le \frac{E\left[e^{t \frac{n}{\sum_{i=1}^n k_i}}\right]}{e^{t(\delta + p)}}$$

Thus to continue from here, I have to compute
$E \left[ exp \left(\frac{nt}{\sum_{i=1}^n k_i}\right)\right]$
I attempted the following steps:

$$\frac{n}{\sum_{i=1}^{n} k_i} \le \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k_i}$$
$$\to E[exp(\frac{nt}{\sum_{i=1}^n k_i})] \le E[e^{t\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k_i}}]$$
$$ = \prod_{i=1}^{n} E[e^{\frac{t}{k_i}}]$$

Now, I focussed on computing $E[e^{\frac{t}{k_i}}]$ which can be written as
$$p \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(1-p)^ie^{\frac{t}{i+1}}$$

And this is where I am stuck. I tried to see if I could do something with the Taylor Series' Expansion of $e^x$ do get some G.P. of the overall some but without luck.

Comment: For a crude upper bound, the expected value is at most the largest possible value.  Since $k_i \ge 1$, that is $\exp(t)$.  Do you need something better than that?

Comment: Yes. I am hoping that I get a bound in terms of $n,t$ and $p$

Comment: Since $e^{t/k_i} > 1$, your product will be greater than $\exp(t)$ if $n$ is large.   There's no point in finding a bound depending on  $n$ if it's worse than a bound that doesn't depend on $n$.

Comment: Actually there is a point. You see $t$ is actually arbitrary with the constraint that $t > 0$. If I get some exponential bound in terms of $n,t$ and $p$, I can minimize this quantity by finding a minima for the exponent w.r.t. $t$.

Comment: Taylor expand $g(x)=e^{t/x}$ around $x=\frac 1{1-p}$ for small $t$ we get: $$=E\exp\left(\frac t{1+\frac {NB(n,p)}n}\right)\le e^{(1-p)t}+\frac 1 22te^{(1-p)t}(\frac 1{1-p}+\frac t 2)(1-p)^4\frac {pr}{n^2(1-p)^2}$$
after noting that $g^{(3)}<0$ and $\mu_3>0$. Large $t$ can be treated separately basically giving the bound mentioned by Robert times a prefactor in $n,p$.

Answer (score 0):

Let me write $\sum_{i=1}^n k_i = S_n$.
$E(k_i) = 1/p$, and $\exp(t/x)$ is a convex function so
$E[\exp(nt/S_n)] \ge \exp(tp)$ by Jensen.  You can't do
any better than that for an upper bound.  On the other hand, for $0 < \alpha < 1$, the theory of large deviations gives you a function $I(\alpha) > 0$ and an asymptotic formula
$$\frac{\log P(S_n < \alpha n/p)}{n} \to -I(\alpha) $$ 
so that 
$$\eqalign{E[\exp(nt/S_n)] &\le e^{tp/\alpha} + P(S_n < \alpha n/p) (e^t - e^{tp/\alpha})\cr
&\sim e^{tp/\alpha} + e^{-n I(\alpha)}(e^t - e^{tp/\alpha})}$$

For a more explicit inequality you might try Chernoff bounds.

Comment: Actually I am already trying to use Chernoff bounds. I will add my work before this step in the next edit.

Comment: How did you get $E[\frac{nt}{S_n}] = tp$? 

Is $E\left[\frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}k_i}\right] = \frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^{n} E[k_i]}$? 

[link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1681323/is-e-left-frac1-sum-i-1nx-i-right-frac1-sum-i-1n-e-left/1681343#1681343)

Comment: No, just look at the two cases $S_n < \alpha n/p)$ and $S_n \ge \alpha n/p$ and bound each.