# Is $E(X^{-1})=\frac{1}{E(X)}$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

If $E$ is the expected value of a random variable, is $E(X^{-1})=\frac{1}{E(X)}$? From the properties of the expected value it looks like this shouldn't be true. However, I have used it in a couple of execises and it seemed to work out okey.

**EDIT**: For example I would like to use this property to calculate $E\left(\frac{X^2}{X^2+Y^2} \right)$ where $X, Y$ are independent stardard normally distributed random variables

Comment: "However, I have used it in a couple of execises and it seemed to work out okey." I don't think so.

Comment: What examples did you try?  Suppose $X=\{\frac 1{10^9},1\}$ with equal probability.

Comment: It may be harder to find a nontrivial example where it does hold.

Comment: Also relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2312138/321264.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now, it's not. In particular, if the variable is strictly positive (and not -almost surely- constant), then, because $g(x)=1/x$ is convex, [Jensen inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality) tells us that

$$E(1/X) > \frac{1}{E(X)}$$

In some cases (eg asymptotics) the equation can be assumed as approximately true (namely if the variance tends to zero) - see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1681423/312).

Comment: Assuming $X$ is not almost surely constant, of course.

Comment: @DarkMalthorp Right, fixed- thanks

Answer (score 3):

If a random variable has an equal chance of being 1 or 2, the expected value is 1.5, so the reciprocal of the expected value is 2/3, but the expected value of the reciprocal is 3/4 (equal chance of being 1/2 or 1).

Answer (score 1):

One way to tell that this should not hold is that it's quite easy to "break" one side while leaving the other intact. For instance:

1. If $X = \pm 1$ with equal probability, then $\mathbb E[X^{-1}]$ is $0$, but $1/\mathbb E[X]$ is undefined.
2. If $X \in \{0, 1\}$ with equal probability, then $\mathbb E[X^{-1}]$ is undefined, while $1 / \mathbb E[X]$ is $2$.